# Cannot get side menu scrollspy to stick on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started with bootstrap 3 and got stuck on an issue. I wanted to have a side menu like in [this](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html) documentation which is positioned fixed during scroll down and highlights sections accordingly. I have managed to get something done very similar to this but when I resize the window to mobile size, the side menu overlaps the content instead of being on top of it. If you checked the link, when you resize the window, the sidemenu goes on top of the content.

I believe the culprit here is `affix-top` but I leave it to the experienced people here in stackoverflow

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#myScrollspy">
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Title
                    <small>Subheading</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Content Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
            <div class="col-md-2" id="myScrollspy">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked affix-top" data-spy="affix" >
                    <li class="active"><a href="#section-1">Section One</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-2">Section Two</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-3">Section Three</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-4">Section Four</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-5">Section Five</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!-- Content Column -->
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <h2 id="section-1">Section One</h2>
                <h2 id="section-2">Section Two</h2>
                <h2 id="section-3">Section Three</h2>
                <h2 id="section-4">Section Four</h2>
                <h2 id="section-5">Section Five</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a CSS media query, which allows you to modify a style rule based on media features such as color, height, and width. The Bootstrap page you linked to uses min- and max-width features to change how the sidebar appears, which you can see in its [CSS file](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/docs.css)near the bottom of the page. The pertinent code looks like this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    /* Adjust sidenav width */
    .bs-docs-sidenav {
        width: 166px;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .bs-docs-sidenav.affix {
        top: 0;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Sidenav */
    .bs-docs-sidenav {
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .bs-docs-sidenav.affix {
        position: static;
        width: auto;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

I have simplified it a little bit, but that should be enough to get you started. When the max-width is less than 768px the sidebar width will change to auto, and the affix code will keep the sidebar at the top of the page.

Comment: That fixed it. I wish I could buy you a coffee. Thanks mate!